# Better way to load images from network flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to load images from network and show them in a `GridView`. I am using a `StatefulWidget` and loading the images inside the `build` method. But according to my understanding its not good to make a network call inside the `build` method. How can I download images from the network inside my `BLoC` file and later pass the list of downloaded images to the widget? Below is my current implementation.

```
class MovieList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MovieListState();
  }
}

class MovieListState extends State<MovieList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bloc.fetchAllMovies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Popular Movies'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.allMovies,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return buildList(snapshot);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> snapshot) {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
        gridDelegate:
        new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GridTile(
            child: InkResponse(
              enableFeedback: true,
              child: Image.network(
                'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${snapshot.data
                    .results[index].poster_path}',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              onTap: () => openDetailPage(snapshot.data, index),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  openDetailPage(ItemModel data, int index) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return MovieDetailBlocProvider(
          child: MovieDetail(
            title: data.results[index].title,
            posterUrl: data.results[index].backdrop_path,
            description: data.results[index].overview,
            releaseDate: data.results[index].release_date,
            voteAverage: data.results[index].vote_average.toString(),
            movieId: data.results[index].id,
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html it's simple to use widget with fade in animation.

Comment: @sagar suri  can you help us share how did you solve the probelm

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I would recommend you to use 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image

It's really works good for my cases.

Simple code example from their r

```
CachedNetworkImage(
   imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
   placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
   errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```

or

```
Image(image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(url))
```

You should add to the pubspec file

```
cached_network_image: <actual version here>
```

into the dependencies section

Comment: I think it can be easily googled by name even if link will be expired but okey, I add a simple sample.

Comment: How does this help me? I want to download images out of my `build` method. I want to do it in a repository file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this way make the image display faster after?

Comment: Is there a way to use the Shimmer widget for loading here? https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer

Comment: `CachedNetworkImage` does not respect container size (you actually need a smaller image to be loaded in memory than the url provides), so you might want to consider this
https://pub.dev/packages/optimized_cached_image

Comment: CachedNetworkImage worked awesomely for me. Thanks Valentin Schukin :)

Comment: The problem with `CachedNetworkImage` is that if network image has been changed it will still show the old image.

Comment: I think it's a good one 

Answer (score 185):

You can use **loadingBuilder** which is inbuilt feature from flutter for Image.Network

```
       Image.network(
                  widget.networkUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                      ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                    if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                            ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                            : null,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: Thanks!
This solution works on for Flutter for web (cached_network_image is not fully supported there)

Comment: what exactly is this child we are passing in?

Comment: Must be the image itself

Comment: This is on of the best answers I have ever seen on stackoverflow

Comment: What if widget.networkUrl is null or empty ?

Comment: @Mohammad you can use errorBuilder argument of Image.network for that

Comment: can we use skeleton here? how as loading builder?

Comment: this didn't solved my problem for Flutter Web...

Comment: I wasn't ever returning child in the loadingBuilder callback, thanks for your help!

Comment: Works like banana

Answer (score 7):

If you want a circular shape for your image. You can use Circle Avatar in such a way that it will act as loader and displayer both....

Parent circle avatar will be having loader and If we put transparent color to child circle avatar it will show loading until it is loaded...

Plus point with this way is you can simply give border also by setting background color of parent circle avatar and increasing it's radius slightly.

```
CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                radius: 65,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/bottombar/loading.gif'),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 65,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_url),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use FadeInImage
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
        placeholder: 'assets/loading.gif',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a good practice to handle errors related to, for example, lack of Internet, when trying to load an image from the Internet. ErrorBuilder is really good if you use Image.network()

```
Image.network(
      'https://example.does.not.exist/image.jpg',
      errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        // Appropriate logging or analytics, e.g.
        // myAnalytics.recordError(
        //   'An error occurred loading "https://example.does.not.exist/image.jpg"',
        //   exception,
        //   stackTrace,
        // );
        return Text('');
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

**Best way to Handle Network Images**

The best way to load image from the network in flutter is to use flutter's *built-in* network function and *customize it according to your requirements*, I do not recommend/prefer to use any package like CachedNetworkImage because it sometimes works on mobile phone and give unexpected error on the web.

You can manage the **Network image** like this:

```
  Image.network(
        netWorkImageURL,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        // When image is loading from the server it takes some time
        // So we will show progress indicator while loading
        loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
            ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
          if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                  ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                      loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                  : null,
            ),
          );
        },
        // When dealing with networks it completes with two states, 
        // complete with a value or completed with an error, 
        // So handling errors is very important otherwise it will crash the app screen. 
        // I showed dummy images from assets when there is an error, you can show some texts or anything you want.
        errorBuilder: (context, exception, stackTrace) {
          return Image.asset(
            AppAssets.dummyPostImg,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: (widget.hideBelowImage == null ||
                    widget.hideBelowImage == false)
                ? 170.h
                : 130.h,
            width: double.infinity,
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: i already try your code and i dont see any loading appear