# NetworkImage with a loading Builder inside a CircleAvatar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to have a network image (NetworkImage / Image.network) using a loading builder inside a CircleAvatar.

I'm a bit new to flutter and learning the kicks but right now I've managed to create:

1. Image.network with a loadingBuilder - **Problem:** CircleAvatar expect an ImageProvider and not an image.
2. NetworkImage within a CircleAvatar - **Problem:** Couldnt find a way to add a loadingBuilder to NetworkImage.

Comment: Can you include sample snippet

Comment: You can refer to this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/59151953/4571266](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59151953/4571266)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                
                foregroundImage: NetworkImage("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553267751-1c148a7280a1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80",
    
              
                ),
              
              ),
```